# Controlling tube light using Arduino-uno

Tags: arduino

I made a light detector circuit using Arduino in which LED glows in dark. Now i want to implement this circuit to tube light but arduino can only give 5v dc output. How to use this 5v dc output to turn on 220v ac tube light?

Comment: You need to use a **relay**, there're plenty of tutorials online for this.

Comment: You should ask this at arduino stack-Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HERE](http://www.instructables.com/id/interface-relay-with-arduino/) you could see a simple way to manage 220VAC with arduino.
The pin that you use now with LED will control the relay. No code changes.